# Spring WS client with signing and encryption

Tags: java, spring, encryption, signing

We have developed a web service using metro 2.0 stack and protected with Username Authentication with Symmetric Key mechanism to protect the web service application. We are working on a sample client using Spring WS.

We were able to do the encryption part (timestamp, encrypted key with X509IssuerSerial and encrypt Soap Body using encrypted key referred in the header). But the signing part is not successful. The security token reference is set to UsernameToken instead of EncryptedKey. Therefore we are getting “WSS1816: Error occurred while resolving Direct Reference”  from server side.

Sample working request (using jax-ws) looks like below

```
    <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
            xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd" 
            xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
            xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
            xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" 
            xmlns:exc14n="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
    <S:Header>
        <To xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" wsu:Id="_5005">AAAAA</To>
        <Action xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" wsu:Id="_5006">AAAAAAAA</Action>
        <ReplyTo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" wsu:Id="_5004">
            <Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</Address>
        </ReplyTo>
        <MessageID xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" wsu:Id="_5003">uuid:940807fd-ce2a-43a8-bc7a-e6c6ff60a0d7</MessageID>
        <wsse:Security S:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsu:Timestamp xmlns:ns19="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2006/02/addressingidentity" 
                           xmlns:ns18="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512" 
                           xmlns:ns17="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" wsu:Id="_3">
                <wsu:Created>2018-10-08T17:19:45Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2018-10-08T17:24:45Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
            <xenc:EncryptedKey xmlns:ns19="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2006/02/addressingidentity" 
                               xmlns:ns18="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512" 
                               xmlns:ns17="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" Id="_5002">
                <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p" />
                <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="KeyInfoType">
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                        <ds:X509Data>
                            <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                                <ds:X509IssuerName>xxxxxxxxxxx</ds:X509IssuerName>
                                <ds:X509SerialNumber>xxxxxxxx</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                            </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                        </ds:X509Data>
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
                <xenc:CipherData>
                    <xenc:CipherValue>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</xenc:CipherValue>
                </xenc:CipherData>
            </xenc:EncryptedKey>
            <xenc:ReferenceList xmlns:ns19="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2006/02/addressingidentity" 
                                xmlns:ns18="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512" 
                                xmlns:ns17="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
                <xenc:DataReference URI="#_5008" />
                <xenc:DataReference URI="#_5009" />
            </xenc:ReferenceList>
            <xenc:EncryptedData xmlns:ns19="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2006/02/addressingidentity" 
                                xmlns:ns18="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512" 
                                xmlns:ns17="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" Id="_5009" 
                                Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element">
                <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc" />
                <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="KeyInfoType">
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                        <wsse:Reference URI="#_5002" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#EncryptedKey" />
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
                <xenc:CipherData>
                    <xenc:CipherValue>xxxxxxxxxxx</xenc:CipherValue>
                </xenc:CipherData>
            </xenc:EncryptedData>
            <ds:Signature xmlns:ns19="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2006/02/addressingidentity" 
                          xmlns:ns18="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512" 
                          xmlns:ns17="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" Id="_1">
                <ds:SignedInfo>
                    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                        <exc14n:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsse S" />
                    </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
                    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#hmac-sha1" />
                    <ds:Reference URI="#_5003">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                <exc14n:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="S" />
                            </ds:Transform>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                        <ds:DigestValue>c9ZlkDDMAW50WAsxUmfyqrlvhxM=</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                    <!-- many other references-->
                </ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:SignatureValue>98jlT6xXmKFw6DiNZWRJ+EQjvk4=</ds:SignatureValue>
                <ds:KeyInfo>
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="uuid_0001ebbf-5b73-42b2-a557-f945301fe28d">
                        <wsse:Reference URI="#_5002" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#EncryptedKey" />
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
            </ds:Signature>
        </wsse:Security>
    </S:Header>
    <S:Body wsu:Id="_5007">
<!-- body data-->        
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Spring bean configurations are like below.

```
@Bean
    public CryptoFactoryBean serverSignatureStoreCryptoFactoryBean() throws IOException, Exception {

        CryptoFactoryBean cryptoFactoryBean = new CryptoFactoryBean();
        Properties cryptoFactoryBeanConfig = new Properties();
        cryptoFactoryBeanConfig.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider", "org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin");
        cryptoFactoryBeanConfig.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type", "jks");
        cryptoFactoryBeanConfig.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password", "pwd");
        cryptoFactoryBeanConfig.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file", "C:\\TestCert.jks");
        cryptoFactoryBean.setConfiguration(cryptoFactoryBeanConfig);
        cryptoFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

        return cryptoFactoryBean;
    }


    @Bean
    public CryptoFactoryBean serverEncryptionStoreCryptoFactoryBean() throws IOException, Exception {

        CryptoFactoryBean cryptoFactoryBean = new CryptoFactoryBean();
        Properties cryptoFactoryBeanConfig = new Properties();
        cryptoFactoryBeanConfig.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider", "org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin");
        cryptoFactoryBeanConfig.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type", "jks");
        cryptoFactoryBeanConfig.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password", "pwd");
        cryptoFactoryBeanConfig.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file", "C:\\TestCert.jks");
        cryptoFactoryBeanConfig.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias", "alias");

        cryptoFactoryBean.setConfiguration(cryptoFactoryBeanConfig);
        cryptoFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

        return cryptoFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor() throws IOException, Exception {
        Wss4jSecurityInterceptor wss4jSecurityInterceptor = new Wss4jSecurityInterceptor();
        wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementActions("Encrypt UsernameTokenSignature Timestamp ");
        wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementUsername("testuser");
        wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementPassword("testpwd");
        wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementPasswordType("PasswordText");


         wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementEncryptionCrypto(serverEncryptionStoreCryptoFactoryBean().getObject());
        wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementEncryptionUser("alias");
        wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementEncryptionParts("{}{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body");


        wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureCrypto(serverEncryptionStoreCryptoFactoryBean().getObject());
        wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureUser("alias");

        wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureKeyIdentifier("DirectReference");    
        wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureParts("{}{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body");
        wss4jSecurityInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet();        

        return wss4jSecurityInterceptor;
    }
```

With above configurations, our request is generated as below

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
                       xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
                       SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-b005d85e-c7e5-4d49-ad77-0672d6a58b29">
                <wsu:Created>2018-10-09T13:43:54.310Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2018-10-09T13:48:54.310Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
            <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd" 
                                wsu:Id="UsernameToken-a895d28f-1f3f-4d9f-85e1-aff8400834b4">
                <wsse:Username>testuser</wsse:Username>
                <wsse11:Salt>xxxxxxxxx</wsse11:Salt>
                <wsse11:Iteration>1000</wsse11:Iteration>
                <wsse:Nonce 
                    EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">
                    xxxxxxxx</wsse:Nonce>
                <wsu:Created>2018-10-09T13:43:54.283Z</wsu:Created>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
            <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="SIG-463b7470-6066-40c2-b598-4e9dec570f3b">
                <ds:SignedInfo>
                    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                        <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="SOAP-ENV"/>
                    </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
                    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#hmac-sha1"/>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#id-fb70c636-999d-4f3b-9715-d79b7a6f275e">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>xxxxxxxx</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                </ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:SignatureValue>xxxxxxxxxx</ds:SignatureValue>
                <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-7d2da23a-61b0-4794-b37a-14d996b93ce3">
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-7b363afe-2dab-4df7-bd1f-9c3f8878d0b6">
                        <wsse:Reference URI="#UsernameToken-a895d28f-1f3f-4d9f-85e1-aff8400834b4" 
                                        ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#UsernameToken"/>
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
            </ds:Signature>
            <xenc:EncryptedKey xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Id="EK-3bd2d6b0-d869-4144-9ad1-19482e525d01">
                <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p"/>
                <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                        <ds:X509Data>
                            <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                                <ds:X509IssuerName>xxxxxxxxxxxx</ds:X509IssuerName>
                                <ds:X509SerialNumber>xxxxxxxxx</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                            </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                        </ds:X509Data>
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
                <xenc:CipherData>
                    <xenc:CipherValue>xxxxxxxxxxx</xenc:CipherValue>
                </xenc:CipherData>
                <xenc:ReferenceList>
                    <xenc:DataReference URI="#ED-4fc0faad-029e-4dd3-9984-8abace8b1e7d"/>
                </xenc:ReferenceList>
            </xenc:EncryptedKey>
        </wsse:Security>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <!-- body data-->        
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```